# Cucumber TAGS execute all tests

Tags: tags, cucumber, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I set up a Cypress project with two systems, it already ran with Cypress 8 and was able to run via tags. I updated to version 13.6 of Cypress and now when running the command

```
npx cypress run TAGS="@login"
```

it runs the tests related to the tag first and then skips through all the application tests. I would like only the tests sent in the tag to be executed, how can I do this?

Cypress.config

```
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");
const createBundler = require("@bahmutov/cypress-esbuild-preprocessor");
const preprocessor = require("@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor");
const createEsbuildPlugin = require("@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/esbuild");

async function setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
  await preprocessor.addCucumberPreprocessorPlugin(on, config);

  on(
    "file:preprocessor",
    createBundler({
      plugins: [createEsbuildPlugin.default(config)],
    })
  );

  return config;
}
```

Package.json

```
 "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": {
    "filterSpecs": true,
    "omitFiltered": true,
    "stepDefinitions": []
}
"dependencies": {
    "@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^20.0.0",
    "@bahmutov/cypress-esbuild-preprocessor": "^2.2.0"
}
```